# Edit Table Localstorage and Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to edit the table stored in localStorage and json, how could it? I'm new and I could only save but not to edit these items in the table.
[image]

Javascript and Jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    cargarDatos();

//document.getElementById('btnGuardar').onclick = mostrarDatos;

    $('#frmContacto').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Bloqueo de comportamiento por defecto de formulario
        guardarDatos();
        cargarDatos();
    });

    $('input').on('blur', function(){
        $(this).addClass('marcado');

    });



    $('.btnEditar').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //Bloqueo de comportamiento por defecto de formulario
        id = this.id;var link = this.href;
        alert(link);
        id = link.substr(link.indexOf("#"), link.length);       
        alert(id);
        editarDatos();
    });

    $('#inputFoto').on('change', function(e) {
        precargarImagen(this);
    });

}); 

//Colección de contactos
//var contactos = new Array();  


function guardarDatos(){
    name = $('#inputNombre').val();
    direccion = $('#inputDireccion').val();
    telefono = $('#inputTelefono').val();
    fecha = $('#inputFecha').val();
    email = $('#inputEmail').val();
    color = $('#inputColor').val();
    dataFoto = $("#imgFoto").attr("src");

    contacto = {
        nombre : name,
        direccion : direccion,
        telefono : telefono,
        fecha : fecha,
        email : email,
        color : color,
        foto : dataFoto
    }; 

    contactos.push(contacto);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(contactos));
    localStorage.setItem('lstcontactos2', JSON.stringify(contactos));

}

function cargarDatos(){

    var data = localStorage.getItem('lstcontactos2');   
    contactos = data && JSON.parse(data);
    if(contactos==null)
        contactos = new Array();

    $('#tablaContactos').bootstrapTable({
        data: contactos
    });


}

/**
 * Formato asociado a tabla boostrapTable para el campo de acciones, con la finalidad
 * que asocie un boton para editar la tarea que posterior sera capturado en el evento clic
 * @param  value    Id de la tarea
 */
function btnEditar(value){
    console.log("valueformat " + value);
    return '<a href="#'+ value +'" class="btn btn-default btnEditar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>';
}

function imgFoto(value){
    return '<img id="imgFoto" src="' + value +
                       '" style="width:auto;height:160px;">';
}


/**
 * Recupera del input:file el archivo seleccionado y lo renderiza en la pantalla
 * @param inputfile     Objeto input de tipo file sobre el que se esta seleccionado la imagen
 */
function precargarImagen(inputfile){
    var file = inputfile.files[0];
    var imageType = /image.*/;

    if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = reader.result;    
            $(".file-caption-name").html(file.name);
            $(".file-preview-frame").empty();
            $(".file-preview-frame").
                append('<img id="imgFoto" src="' + reader.result +
                       '" style="width:auto;height:160px;">');
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
        inputfile.val(img.src);
    } else {
        alert("Archivo no soportando!");
    }
}
```

How i did? Examples? i'm new please.